# Can't understand why "frozen" random variable isn't working right from scipy.stats in Python

Tags: python-3.x, scipy

I've used frozen Random Variables (RVs) from scipy.stats in Python.  For reasons I can't understand I get different behavior between a script and an interactive session:

```
from scipy.stats import norm, lognormal
import math as math

RV = lognorm(s=.8325546, scale=math.exp(-.34657359))  # frozen RV with many attributes

print("\ntrial of lognorm: ")
print(" " + str(lnRV(2)))
```

fails, saying:

```
TypeError: 'rv_frozen' object is not callable
```

Oddly, I can get this to work OK in an interactive session, for both the normal and lognormal:

[image: Python Interactive]

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: `lnRV(2)` and `lnRV.cdf(2)` are not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid on my part...I am defining an instance using RV, but then trying to call an instance using lnRV.